# Installing ubuntu server using Network Console

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, virtualbox, ssh

I have a bit of a weird situation, I have a laptop (an old Macbook 3,1) with a half broken screen. I want to install Ubuntu server on the computer but it turns out to be quite a difficult endeavour. the best option I've found is using the Network console and using VM to see whats on the screen and start the ssh server (I can't use that to install "regularly" because the VM stops being identical to the mac at the partition manager, when iv'e tried it I ended up with a 4 partitioned mac). Alas, when I try to login with ssh as instructed by the installer the mac returns a message saying I must generate an encryption pair.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ meitarnaveh$ ssh installer@10.0.0.20
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
3f:8f:d9:a2:2c:f3:9d:c3:88:bc:eb:c7:e3:a7:f0:b9.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/meitarnaveh/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/meitarnaveh/.ssh/known_hosts:5
RSA host key for 10.0.0.20 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

this BTW is me trying to connect to the VM which also doesn't work.
I have successfully connected once, to the VM  on my first try and it hasn't worked since.
ps. I have another screen connected with a cable but the computer doesn't display anything during the installation on it. in the installed system it displays no problem.

thanks in advance and sorry for any grammatical errors, english isn't my native language.

Attached is a picture of the screen for your enjoyment.

[image]

edit: I've added a syslog part that might help

```
Oct 13 06:47:01 sshd[8086]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 13 06:47:01 sshd[8086]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 13 06:47:01 apt-install: Queueing package openssh-server for later installation
Oct 13 06:47:04 sshd[8099]: WARNING: /etc/ssh/moduli does not exist, using fixed modulus
Oct 13 06:47:04 sshd[8099]: Connection closed by 10.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This message comes up because you have connected to a machine with the IP address of 10.0.0.20 before and the machine you are now connecting too doesn't have the same fingerprint for the RSA key.

If that IP address is one that you often use for your test machines or VMs then simply edit ~/.ssh/known_hosts on your MacBook Pro and remove the entry for 10.0.0.20

The next time you try to ssh it should ask you if you want to save the RSA fingerprint.

Comment: It's generally preferable to use a specialised tool to edit `known_hosts` and friends, because you might accidentally lock yourself out, if you make a mistake. In this case: `ssh-keygen -R 10.0.0.20`